# Passing different UIButtons through a general Method. Are Selectors/Senders the answer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, methods, uibutton, selector

I have about 20 buttons added from Interface Builder, and when pressed they change colour like so:

```
-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender
{
    if(playerTurn == YES)
    {
        button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

But to shorten things it seems like I could just have a general method, so that every button when pressed runs the method. Something like:

```
-(IBAction)button1:(id)sender
{
    //Go to method and make this button red
}
-(void)changeColour
{
    if(playerTurn == YES)
    {
        buttonThatWasSent.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I can't figure out how to do that. It seems selectors/senders are the answer? But I've not managed to make any tutorials I've found work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were pretty close!

```
- (IBAction)myActionWithAnArbitraryName:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if(playerTurn == YES) {
        [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can link all the 20 buttons of a single action.

The sender knows which button was pressed, so directly channge the backgroundColor of sender.

```
-(IBAction)changeColour:(id)sender
{
    if (playerTurn == YES)
        sender.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
}
```

Note:This is not tested code. But i guess it should work, if wont they try do this way:

```
UIButton *button=(UIButton *)sender;
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use a single IBAction for all your buttons and just cast the sender as a UIButton:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    if (playerTurn == YES) {
        button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
}
```